# OpenCV Up Scaling only works with "EDSR" model (Python Command script written in Visual Studio)

Tags: python, opencv

Long time reader, first time poster.

I am attempting to edit a small .png file using the code shown below.  With the '/EDSR_x3' model, I am getting results after it processes.  Where I run into issues is using any of the other models.  They all give the same error shown below.

**Error Message**
"OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'cv::merge'"

**Code**

```
from ast import Try
import string
from tkinter import END
import easygui
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

print("Script Started")

# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('./onlinesample.png')

print("read model")
# Read the desired model
path = './EDSR_x3.pb' #tooo slow
#path = './ESPCN_x4.pb' #try faster?
#path = './FSRCNN_X4.pb' #try this?
sr.readModel(path)

print("set model")
# Set the desired model and scale to get correct pre- and post-processing
sr.setModel("edsr", 2) #working on small file very slowly
#sr.setModel("espcn", 2) #try other model, no luck
#sr.setModel("fsrcnn", 2) #try a differetn one, no work

print("upscale Started")
# Upscale the image
result = sr.upsample(image) # no worky *this is where I get the error*

print("img_displaying")
#crop_cropped = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
cv2.imshow('upscaled', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I tried a few different input files, same results with each, errors for everything except the '/EDSR_x3'.

Comment: [mre] required. complete traceback required. your code never calls `merge()`. I wonder where that might be called... *traceback required*